# PHP. Заменить мнемоники на их значения, даже если их несколько

Tags: php

Есть переменная со значением:

```
$var = "Фильтр всасывающий Champion 50 (2&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;#039;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;#039;) DP50E";
```

Подскажите как можно заменить мнемоники на их значения, даже если их несколько, что бы они сложились все по цепочке?

Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Шесть раз через `html_entity_decode` ;)

Comment: А одной строкой можно это сделать, при условии если может быть разное кол-во повторений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "Фильтр всасывающий Champion 50 (2&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;#039;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;#039;) DP50E";
```

```
$n = substr_count($str, ';'); // Подсчитываем сколько циклов нужно выполнить

for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
    $str = html_entity_decode($str);
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: Будут лишние циклы + наличие `;` не обязательно говорит о присутствии спецсимвола

Answer (score 0):

> А одной строкой можно это сделать, при условии если может быть разное
> кол-во повторений?

```php
function decode_chained($s)
{
    while(($r = $s) != ($s = html_entity_decode($s)));
    return $r;
}

$var = "Фильтр всасывающий Champion 50 (2&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;#039;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;#039;) DP50E";

echo decode_chained($var);
// Фильтр всасывающий Champion 50 (2'') DP50E
```

Comment: Подскажите как мне этим кодом воспользоваться ? У меня есть только $var, как мне вывести результат на экран?

Comment: @АлексейСердюк Дополнил ответ. Один раз определяете функцию и используете где нужно. Хотя я задумался, крайние мнемоники должны оставаться или нет?